# module.exports a jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I'm trying to `module.exports` a jQuery plugin (for use with Browserify) but I'm having a bit of difficulty. It's the [jquery.adaptive-backgrounds](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js) plugin I'm trying to `require()` as a module.

My current setup looks like this:

**adaptive-backgrounds.js**

```
module.exports = {
  /* adaptive-backgrounds script goes here */
  ;(function($){
  ...
}
```

**app.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
var ab = require('./vendors/adaptive-backgrounds');

$(function() {
  $.ab.run();
});
```

For whatever reason though, the script isn't being run. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

If anyone has any experience with this, I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the `;(function($){` bit about?

Comment: @JMM That's what the plugin looks like: https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js/blob/master/src/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js

Answer (score 0):

The content of `adaptive-backgrounds.js` doesn't look like it's shaping up to even be valid JS.

You may just need something like:

`adaptive-backgrounds.js`:

```js
var jQuery = require('jquery');

/* adaptive-backgrounds script goes here */
;(function($){
...
```